# Custom ROS Service Cannot be Imported

Tags: ros, python, rospy, rosservice, ros-noetic

I have created a simple custom ROS service for ROS Noetic. My import line is:

```
from fishbot_ros.srv import chess_service, chess_serviceResponse
```

The file structure is like this:

```
.
└── parent
    ├── src
    │   └── chess_node.py
    └── srv
        └── chess_service.srv
```

The service is generated correctly and is viewable by `rossrv show`. I have cleaned `devel` and `build` subfolders and then executed `catkin make`.

My CMakeLists.txt has the following sections:

```
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  rospy
  message_generation
  std_msgs
)

add_service_files(
  FILES
  chess_service.srv
)
```

My package.xml has the following:

```
  <buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>
  <build_depend>rospy</build_depend>
  <build_export_depend>rospy</build_export_depend>
  <build_export_depend>std_msgs</build_export_depend>
  <exec_depend>rospy</exec_depend>
  <exec_depend>std_msgs</exec_depend>
  <build_depend>message_generation</build_depend>
  <exec_depend>message_runtime</exec_depend>
```

Please help me understand what I'm doing wrong. I did this for a different project a while ago, and I've done everything the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange!

If `my_ros_pkg` and `MyService.srv` are the name of the ROS package and name of the service file, respectively, please use the following line to import the service:

```
from my_ros_pkg.srv import MyService, MyServiceRequest, MyServiceResponse
```

Comment: Hi Ravi, thanks for your comment. Unfortunately, this did not work, I still got the same error as below:

`from fishbot_ros.srv import chess_service, chess_serviceResponse ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fishbot_ros'`

Comment: I assume `fishbot_ros` is ROS pkg. You may look at following: 1. [CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/ravijo/multiple_kinect_baxter_calibration/blob/5b883da744799abbf78f400f40e142d8450a7c9d/CMakeLists.txt) and [Python Node](https://github.com/ravijo/multiple_kinect_baxter_calibration/blob/5b883da744799abbf78f400f40e142d8450a7c9d/scripts/robot_controller.py)
2. [CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/ravijo/ros_openpose/blob/21e6c3e23bd49340e04aee1341e894142d9f66e7/CMakeLists.txt) and [Python Node](https://github.com/ravijo/ros_openpose/blob/21e6c3e23bd49340e04aee1341e894142d9f66e7/scripts/echo.py)

Comment: Thank you Ravi. The issue was in my CMakeLists. I had the generate messages section commented out.